# Why is my memoized calculation failing?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, floating-accuracy

I am trying to turn a two dimensional recursion problem into a dynamic programming problem. But the results are different.

Here is the code:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static double binomial(int N, int k, double p) {
        if(N == 0 && k == 0) return 1.0;
        if(N < 0 || k < 0) return 0.0;
        return (1 - p)*binomial(N-1, k, p) + p*binomial(N-1, k-1, p);
    }

    public static double binomialm(int N, int k, double p) {
        if(N < 0 || k < 0) return 0.0;

        double[][] memory = new double[N+1][k+1];
        memory[0][0] = 1.0;
        memory[1][0] = 1 - p;
        memory[0][1] = 0.0;

        for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j <= k; j++) {
                memory[i][j] = (1 - p)*memory[i-1][j] + p*memory[i-1][j-1];
            }
        }

        return memory[N][k];
    }

    static public void main(String args[]) {
        long stime, stime1, etime, etime1;
        double r, r1;
        stime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        r = binomial(10, 5, 0.25);
        etime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Regular binomial: result = " + r + ", time = " + (etime - stime));
        stime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        r1 = binomialm(10, 5, 0.25);
        etime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Memoized binomial: result = " + r1 + ", time = " + (etime1 - stime1));
    }
}
```

I really cannot figure out why the results are different. Here they are:

Regular binomial: result = 0.058399200439453125, time = 0

Memoized binomial: result = 0.045421600341796875, time = 0

Is there some floating point magic that I am missing?

Comment: There are so few teachers who themselves know and can properly teach Dynamic Programming that I already have deep respect for anyone who attempts to learn it. :D If someone has a good link that clearly explains DynaPro and systematically explains writing its code, please name tag me and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In your memoized version, your inner loop starts from `j = 1`. Therefore, the values for (2,0), (3,0), (4,0), ... are never changed, they are all still 0.0 from the creation of the double array. They are supposed to be 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, ...

```
for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    memory[i][0] = (1 - p)*memory[i-1][0];
    for(int j = 1; j <= k; j++) {
        memory[i][j] = (1 - p)*memory[i-1][j] + p*memory[i-1][j-1];
    }
}
```